# What is wrong with this attempt to create a route to delete a record in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called NoteCategory, which is functioning as a join table between Notes and Categories.

Up till this point, I have used scaffolding to do everything in RoR. I'm trying to learn how to do some stuff more manually.

I want to have a link that will appear next to each category on a note, that will remove the category from the note. So I need to create a route that will delete the entry from the join table.

So far I have created a controller

```
class NoteCategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
      notecategory = NoteCategory.find(params[:id])
      notecategory.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(notes_url) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
    end
end
```

I then added this line to routes.db

```
map.resources :note_categories
```

And here is the link in the view:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :controller => "notecategories",:action => :destroy %>
```

When I click the button, I get this error message:

```
No route matches "/notecategories/destroy" with {:method=>:post}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map.resources` doesn't create `/$controller/destroy` route. Run `rake routes` and see what exactly you have.

As for having it right, this 'delete' button is generated by scaffold command for simple CRUD application, so it should work.

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

**edit**
Whole 'index.html.erb' page generated by 'scaffold' command. It should give you general idea.

```
<h1>Listing events</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
  </tr>

<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h event.name %></td>
    <td><%=h event.budget %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New event', new_event_path %>
```

Comment: I didn't used the `event` before, could you tell me more about that? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterWong It's an object you want to destroy. I just've taken example from page generated for "Event" model by "script/generate scaffold event name:string".

Comment: Ooops, sorry for missing the declaration line. :D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :controller => "notecategories",:action => :destroy, :method => :delete %>
```

Note the :method

It's because of the RESTful routes use those PUT, DELETE, POST, etc action words with together the paths (ie. /notecategories/destroy with :delete together for destroying records)